# How to disconnect laptop battery as it's removed physically but without removing it?

Tags: batteries

The story is the battery indicator in my Dell XPS laptop is flashing. 3 ambers and 1 white repeatedly all the time. It's not just that it makes few beeps at start up and i have to click F1 to continue. So I made my research and probably it's time to replace a new battery. But I am happy to use without battery as I never move it from my desk.

Those people with Dell laptops would know the problem which is that the battery is acting as 2 back legs on the laptop. If I removed the battery physically, it means i need to put something there to raise the laptop without blocking the airflow.

So I want to leave the battery where it belongs without using it so that the computer won't beep at start up and the battery indicator won't keep flashing all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the case of the battery pack.  Remove the cells and the battery pack's circuit board.  Close the the battery pack case and use it as the mechanical void-filler with legs.

The Laptop detects the presence of the battery, through the electrical connections to the circuit board inside the battery pack.  So, the laptop should act as if the battery is not present.

**meta**
This is a borderline question for EE.SE.  It might work equally well (or better) at SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have my reason to put the first paragraph .. you removed that and now people misunderstood and now i am having down votes :(

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use packing tape.

Simply put tape over flat battery connector. Spring pins are too weak to break tape and tape is too thin to disturb connector much.

Comment: Most battery packs do not use spring pins, they use fixed fins that slide into slots.